# Cut video into multiple short videos

Tags: video, video-editing

I have 4 large video files, about 10h each, and 10GB each. Those are recordings of 4 days of sport event. During this sport event there were hundreds of 3min to 15min maches. I want to cut these videos into parts and each part should consist only of one match.

As I understand, in video edition software I would have to open this huge file, then select the match, cut this part, discard the rest, save as separate file, repeat. This is time consuming.

Do you know any software in which i can open this huge file and then select parts i want to save and then save them as separate files each? It would save me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: You can script it with ffmpeg and `-ss` and `-t`

Comment: Programmatically I'd chop to equal length short clips - perhaps 2 minutes each or maybe even 1 minute, depending on system resources.  Name them by time.  Then generate a few thumbnails from them.  Now you can quickly put together "a few" of them and re-join the clips, trim appropriately if needed, and save as the actual video you want to save.  Unless you have start/end times, duration, etc available in a parseable format eventually a human has to decide "game footage" vs "between game".  But starting with small clips and thumbnails will help a lot.

Comment: If there is a consistent image between matches, be it cutting from the match to the commentator or a caption at a specific portion of the screen then you could use MoviePy (below) to seek out those items and split based on them. For example if the sporting event is always played on grass and there is always a studio scene between matches you could split on the frames where green < 30% of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

With [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) you can do this and possibly, with a little bit of work, if the there are a limited number of start/end screens have it automatically split based on finding them in a similar way to how the [Soccer Cuts Example](https://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/07/04/automatic-soccer-highlights-compilations-with-python/) selects sequences based on the sound level.

You would need to isolate the start/end screens and then have it scan through the file once looking for the time stamps of the start/end sequences and then a second time to cut the file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a media conversion program called M²Convert Professional that has, among other things, a special dialog for splitting videos. (Disclaimer: The company I work for owns this product).

One of the options is to display a player window that lets you select portions by seeking and playing the large video. You can add as many split portions as you need before you close the dialog, then it performs splitting based on the list of portions you selected.

The [Split dialog is documented here](http://www.m2solutionsinc.com/help/m2pro/DLLDlg/SplitMediaFileDialog.htm) and the [Select Portions Dialog here](http://www.m2solutionsinc.com/help/m2pro/DLLDlg/SelectPortiontoConvertDialog.htm).

If you want to consider using it, I recommend trying the free evaluation before you make a purchase, to make sure it works the way you want it. You can [get it from here](http://www.m2solutionsinc.com/).